# How would I set the fourth class in a div for a specific page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I modify the JavaScript below using jquery?

It works without jquery, but since we are in fact, using jquery, there must be a simpler way.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript CSS Test1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .test{
                font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;
                color:navy;
                font-size:20px;
                padding-top:10px;
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;
                padding-bottom:20px;
                border:5px solid lime;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="test">
                Test1
            </div>
            <div class="test">
                Test2
            </div>
            <div class="test">
                Test3
            </div>
            <div class="test">
                Test4
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload=function(){
                var loc=location.href;
                if(loc.indexOf("javascript-css-test1")!=-1){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[3].style.paddingBottom="3px";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I have to integrate the code into the existing js which has variables for several other urls, and functions as constructors to initialize other functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a question like that, if it work without jQuery, why would you want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You can done it with css very easily

```
div:nth-child(4)
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Where is the logic for `if(loc.indexOf("javascript-css-test1")!=-1){`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery code :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    loc = location.href
    if(loc.indexOf("javascript-css-test1")!=-1){
        $(".test:nth-child(4)").css({'padding-bottom': '3px'})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eq` selector for jQuery

```
if(loc.indexOf("javascript-css-test1")!=-1){
   $(".test").eq('3').css({paddingBottom : '3px'});
                      or
   $(".test:eq(3)").css({paddingBottom : '3px'});
}
```